# save an Access database with restricted permissions for users

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a question about a feature and I don't know if it's applied in Microsoft Access or not. After I finish my database tables, forms and reports, I want the user just to open forms and these forms will do most the tasks which are adding, deleting or modifying the records. I don't want the end user to see the other object such as tables, or to view or change the layout of the forms.

Is there any way to save the database just as exe file or limiting the permissions of the end users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no version is supplied, I'll give you what I know about MS Access 2007.

Take a quick look at [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-the-access-2007-file-format-HA010067831.aspx)

What you need is to convert your accdb file to accde. This will hide the navigation pane and forbid any action from being taken on your forms.

> An .accde file is a "locked-down" version of the original .accdb file.
>   If the .accdb file contains any Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)
>   code, only the compiled code is included in the .accde file. As a
>   result, the VBA code cannot be viewed or modified by the user. Also,
>   users working with .accde files cannot make design changes to forms or
>   reports.

The same was also true for earlier versions, i.e. mdb to mde for Access 2003. I am sure that there is something for newer versions of MS Access as well.

Hope I helped.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I use 2010 and I get a way to save the file as .accde but I think it can't be opened without access runtime but I'm not sure If I need to install it on a pc which already have microsoft access ?!

Comment: Access runtime is required to run accdr files if microsoft access is not installed. If the computer already has the full microsoft access installation, you should not have a problem.